# Show all records for the same ID

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I'm working on a Access project and I need help with something..

I have 2 tables, first one named tblHoliday, with fields (ID, OfficerID, OffType, From, To) [From] and [To] are Date Fields.

The second table is tblService with fields (ID, OfficerID, Date).
There is a relationship between [OfficerID] in each table.

Every [OfficerID] **may have two records or more** in a table tblService,, 
I designed a form for tblHoliday to enter the officer's holiday, my question is (I need to check if any [Date] for the same [OfficerID] in the table tblService between [From] and [To], for OfficerID in the table tblHoliday), example: an officer ask for a holiday from 1/1/2017 to 1/10/2017 if he has a service in 1/3/2017 will give a message "the officer has a service on 1/3/2017"

My code works, but only for the first record in tblService for the same OfficerID

```
    Dim dtmMyDate As Date   
    dtmMyDate = DLookup("Date", "tblService", "OfficerID = " & Me.OfficerID)

    If dtmMyDate > Me.From And dtmMyDate < Me.To Then
        MsgBox "The Officer has a Service"
    Else
        MsgBox "Done"
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a query:

```
Select 
    tblService.*
    tblHoliday.*
Where
    tblService.OfficerID = tblHoliday.OfficerID
    And
    tblService.Date Between tblHoliday.From And tblHoliday.To
```

Open a *recordset* from this or assign it to a *listbox* to either loop or list the offending service days.

Comment: thanks for answer .. but I don't really get it .. all i need is a MsgBox in the form when i enter the data

Comment: Then open this query as a recordset and loop this where you add each found officer's name to a string variable. Prefix a `vbCrLf` if not the first record. Finally, use the variable as Prompt for your message box to show the list of names.